# How to pass an Api connection object and use it in different activities

Tags: java, android, mikrotik

I'm using [Mikrotik Java API](https://github.com/GideonLeGrange/mikrotik-java) in my android project

what i'm trying to achieve is :

- Login with the info
- Store the connection in the background
- Use the connection in all the actitives, sharing the`ApiConnection` in different activities to use it like `con.login()` `con.execute()` from any activity

i've the login form, after submiting it, it sends the info and starts an [intentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), there i make the connection

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        try {
            String host = intent.getStringExtra("host");
            String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
            String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");

            ApiConnection con = ApiConnection.connect(host);
            con.login(username, password);

            // Connected

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Exception
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Exception
    }
}
```

I succedded making the connection from that intentService, but i can't handle the exceptions if there is a connection problem, also [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) messages doesn't show in the *onHandleIntent*

i think what i'm doing does not make any sense, and no logic.

How could i achieve something like that?

Comment: Create class which holds singleton instance of your connection api and then use it in different activities. as it is singleton it will share same object so once connected it will be connected for all.

Comment: Well, how can i send the login form info to that singleton class to perform the login authentication, how can i include it in every activity, can you write the structure for it? thanks.

Comment: Use singleton for only make one connection not for operations. What I mean is that you create class which hold connection then every time get connected object from that class and then perform operations in individual activity or fragment. To know more about singleton check this - http://idiotechie.com/singleton-design-pattern-an-introspection-and-best-practices

Comment: I understand you, i have a login form so the logic is sending the login form info after submiting it to make the (one) connection in that signleton class, then how can i use it (the ApiConnection) in different activities and do operations in those activities like con.execute()? should i include it in every activity? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare con object as static in main activity where you getting connection, and then use it anywhere as per your requirement,

See below structure,

**In Main Activity**

```
   public static ApiConnection con;
```

**On Getting Connection**

```
    con = ApiConnection.connect(host);
```

**Crate one method to get this connection in main activity as below**

```
   public static ApiConnection getCon()
    {
        if(con != null)
           return con;
         else
           return null;
    }
```

**Now use this object in any activity by below code**

```
   ApiConnection con = = MainActivity.getCon();
   if(con != null)
    {
       // Use Your Logic Here
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "On Getting Connection"? i can't perform any network operations in the main activity, i have to use AsynTask in the background, can you explain it more? thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

@Amr SubZero I don't have api setup and all so i just created this classes to explain you flow.

```
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Wasim on 18-06-2016.
 */
public class SingletonApiConnection {

    private static final String TAG = "SingletonApiConnection";

    private static SingletonApiConnection apiInstance = null;

    private SingletonApiConnection() {
    }

    public SingletonApiConnection(String host) {
        apiInstance.connect(host);
        Log.d(TAG, "Object Created.");
    }

    public static SingletonApiConnection getInstance(String host) {

        if (null == apiInstance) {
            apiInstance = new SingletonApiConnection(host);
        }

        return apiInstance;
    }
}
```

Intent service

```
public class NetworkRequestService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public NetworkRequestService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // get object with host
        String host = intent.getStringExtra("host");
        SingletonApiConnection connection = SingletonApiConnection.getInstance(host);

        String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");

        // now call login
        connection.login(username, password);

        // now use this at any class it will have loggedin instance b'z it is singleton.

    }
}
```

And in login

```
Intent networkService = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NetworkRequestService.class);
// add intent parameters here
startService(networkService);
```

Comment: I get a warning that .connect in the singleton class not defined, that's because i have to import the class i'm using "mikrotik" also in the intentService where connection.login() so where should i import the class "mikrotik"? to define those functions .connect & .connection? another thing, can i use the object "connection" in all the activites like connection.excute()? Thanks @androidnoobdev